# Deployment issue for blazor server/client app to google appengine

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, dockerfile, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor (.NET 6) server/client application and am trying to deploy it to google appengine.  The app runs fine locally in Visual Studio when I launch it with https or as Container (Dockerfile).  When I go to deploy it and run

`gcloud app deploy`

I get this error:

```
Step 8/18 : RUN dotnet restore "./SevenOfNine/Server/SevenOfNine.Server.csproj"
 ---> Running in b72b6927c101
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ./SevenOfNine/Server/SevenOfNine.Server.csproj
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "./SevenOfNine/Server/SevenOfNine.Server.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SevenOfNine/Server/SevenOfNine.Server.csproj", "SevenOfNine/Server/"]
COPY ["SevenOfNine/Server/holodeckhub-da6f4d98c75e.json", "SevenOfNine/Server/"]
COPY ["SevenOfNine.Models/SevenOfNine.Models.csproj", "SevenOfNine.Models/"]
COPY ["SevenOfNine/Client/SevenOfNine.Client.csproj", "SevenOfNine/Client/"]
COPY ["SevenOfNine/Shared/SevenOfNine.Shared.csproj", "SevenOfNine/Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./SevenOfNine/Server/SevenOfNine.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SevenOfNine/Server"
RUN dotnet build "./SevenOfNine.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./SevenOfNine.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SevenOfNine.Server.dll"]
```

And here is my app.yaml, in case that is helpful:

```
    runtime: custom
    env: flex
```

I am running the gcloud app deploy from the Server folder.
The folder structure is:

```
\BorgCollective\
   BorgCollective.sln
   .dockerignore
   SevenOfNine\
      Server\
         SevenOfNine.Server.csproj
         Dockerfile
      Client\
         SevenOfNine.Client.csproj
```

And just to be thorough, here is my .dockerignore file

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
!**/.gitignore
!.git/HEAD
!.git/config
!.git/packed-refs
!.git/refs/heads/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of my issue was answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933022/deploy-blazor-application-to-google-app-engine).  I'm still making a separate answer here to spell out the steps in more detail.  Assuming you have your app ready to deploy to Google App Engine and you've already installed the Google Cloud CLI.

1. Go to your blazor server project and replace your Dockerfile with the one from the linked answer.
2. Publish your app in Release mode.
3. Open a command prompt, navigate to your server app's folder and type `gcloud app deploy`
4. Verify the values that it says it will be deploying to.
5. Press Y to continue.
6. Once the deployment is complete, click on the link at the end of the console log output to verify that the web app was successfully deployed.